# Fix Screen orientation

Tags: android, android-layout, android-manifest

I wanted to fix screen orientation as a landscape mode in tab i.e on 7"
I am calculating the inch of the device in my coding and is setting it as:

```
int inch=((int)height_pixel1/(int)xdpi);
if(inch>=6){
    orientation=true;
    this.setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE);
} else {
    orientation=false;
    this.setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT);
}
```

and the problem is firstly it displays me the screen orientation as according to my requirement,but when processing is going on in between , then it changes the orientation as portrait way and again in landscape way.. It is still toggle between these two orientation and I want to make a fixed orienattion for my whole application...Is there any property that I am missing here??

Comment: Kanika if you got the answer, please mark the correct one accepted

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a folder layout-xlarge-land  and put your XML in it... it should be designed for landsacpe screen.. also You have to give

```
android:largeScreens="true"  in manifest... 


res/layout/my_layout.xml             // layout for normal screen size ("default")
res/layout-small/my_layout.xml       // layout for small screen size
res/layout-large/my_layout.xml       // layout for large screen size
res/layout-xlarge/my_layout.xml      // layout for extra large screen size
res/layout-xlarge-land/my_layout.xml // layout for extra large in landscape orientation





 <supports-screens android:resizeable=["true"| "false"]
                      android:smallScreens=["true" | "false"]
                      android:normalScreens=["true" | "false"]
                      android:largeScreens=["true" | "false"]
                      android:xlargeScreens=["true" | "false"]
                      android:anyDensity=["true" | "false"]
                      android:requiresSmallestWidthDp="integer"
                      android:compatibleWidthLimitDp="integer"
                      android:largestWidthLimitDp="integer"/>
```

**Refer** 
http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/providing-resources.html

Comment: The os in which I am working is 2.2 so it shows that it is not supporting xlargescreens..

Comment: then you use layout-large-land also give : android:largeScreens="true"

Comment: It will assume largeScreen from 5" so it will also consider HTC desire HD in large screen and shows landscape mode there..but i want only 7" and 10.1" inch tab to go for landscape mode only..

Answer (score 1):

Try it out, just set it inside the AndroidManifest.xml file:

```
<activity android:name=".ActivityName"
              android:label="@string/app_name"
              android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden">  
              // Prevent application restart on orientation change
```

Comment: no...because this app is running on 7" tab and also on mobile ..so I want to set orientation as landscape on 7" tab and portait on mobile device..so If I will apply this screen orienation as portait in manifest then it will display application only in portait mode,not in landscape mode..

Comment: but I want to fix the orientation, I dont want it to change..On mobile its working fine in portrait mode,but on 7"tab ,it is toggling between the orientation..

Answer (score 0):

please have a look at this 
.........

```
supports-screens android:resizeable=["true"| "false"]
              android:smallScreens=["true" | "false"]
              android:normalScreens=["true" | "false"]
              android:largeScreens=["true" | "false"]
              android:xlargeScreens=["true" | "false"]
              android:anyDensity=["true" | "false"]
              android:requiresSmallestWidthDp="integer"
              android:compatibleWidthLimitDp="integer"
              android:largestWidthLimitDp="integer
```

...............
It will be Handle your screen