# How to fix orientation problems?

Tags: android, android-orientation

When i changed screen from portrait mode to land scape mode then automatically came out from my application.(same as landscape to portrait also)can any one tell me the solution for this..

this is my code for orientation,

```
if (this.getResources().getConfiguration().orientation == Configuration.ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT) {
            Toast.makeText(MyAlphabetsActivity.this, "ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT",
                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            setContentView(R.layout.portrait_main);
            System.out.println("int-----1--");
        } else if (this.getResources().getConfiguration().orientation == Configuration.ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE) {
            setContentView(R.layout.landscape_main);
            Toast.makeText(MyAlphabetsActivity.this, "ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE",
                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            System.out.println("int-----2--");
        }
```

when change portrait to landscape control entered into else if() and display Toast massage also.......

Comment: Do you mean, your app is crashing on orientation change..?

Comment: Could you give more information about it? For example logcat.

Comment: my application was closed...i added orientation code please check it .....

Comment: Check this link : 


 http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8209349/fix-screen-orientation/8209543#8209543

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have same layout in `portrait` as well as in the `landscape` mode then its better to stop the re-creation of Activity on rotation change by adding

```
android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden"
```

attribute in your activity tag in the Manifest file.

Comment: i added line of code to manifest file,same problem...i added my orientation code please check it once ...i made mistake some where please help me

Comment: @Chiru check [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7749675/how-to-stop-changing-the-orientation-when-a-progress-bar-is-spinning-in-android/7749727#7749727) answer.

Comment: did you get the log when the orientation changes?

Comment: no....when the application launch that time only got logs and toast massages ...either landscape or portrait

Answer (score 1):

You incorrectly handle the orientation change. You should read [Handling Runtime Changes](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/runtime-changes.html) guide. Consider [this](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/fundamentals/activities.html#ConfigurationChanges) as well.

Answer (score 0):

You have two options: either you block the application in a single mode: portrait or landscape. 
Second option is to create two layouts: layout-land and layout-portrait
It is not correct to have two different layouts. It just not work.
You must have to folders in res folder. One folder layout-land in which you have your main.xml 
And a folder layout-portrait in which you have a file called also main.xml with handling the portrait mode.

Comment: i created two folder and how to import layouts in two folder(R.layout.main)...please help me

Comment: you you dont need to import...it's just happening. You need to write setContentView(R.layout.main) and function of your orientation the app will know to look in the layout land folder or in the layout portrait folder. In these folders you need to copy the same main.xml file, and make some modifications of layout according to orientation. Anyway....they are not necessarly modifcations...layout may be exactly the same...just will not look good....you can try let it same in the first try.

Answer (score 0):

```
int o = getBaseContext().getResources().getConfiguration().orientation;
    if(o==1)//Portrait
    {
             Log.i("Portrait","=====");

    }
    else if(o==2)//Landscape
    {
             Log.i("Landscape","=====");
    }
```

Comment: thanks dude ....it's working fine....but it is taken only one layout means suppose we change portrait to landscape it's taken portrait and same as landscape